# Webcam with good driver

Tags: camera, video-camera

After loving my older Logitechs with good drivers, my newest (920) insists on using the tremendously bad Logitech Capture program to do things like zoom in and out.  That program is simply next to useless, with huge delays and quality issues.

Try as I might, I can't figure out which cameras actually have good drivers that allow me to tilt, pan, zoom, so I thought I'd ask for recommendations.

- This is for Windows 10, videoconferencing, likely using Zoom
- It needs a USB2 interface
- Needs a microphone
- Needs a tripod screw mount
- Needs good software that allows control of at least Zoom (NOT Logitech Capture!!)
- I'd like it to be between $50-$100 USD
- Braindead easy to use (e.g., restreaming and changing the camera source for an application like Zoom is a non-starter, even if the software worked well, unlike Logitech Capture).  This is because this is for my students to use, and I want them to be able to do it with minimum support.

I feel bad about asking.  So help me, I've been buying hardware for almost 4 decades, I'm pretty good at it, but finding out which drivers cameras use seems to be very difficult.  My home camera (Logitech C270) uses Logitech Webcam Controller, and works fine, but has no tripod thread.  I've been looking for a camera that uses Webcam Controller or HD Webcam controller, but there are cons listed for those apps that not all cameras are compatible, but they don't provide a compatibility list!!!!  My last purchase was a C920 -- beautiful image, but the Capture software is simply unacceptable, and I'm disappointed with the purchase.

Comment: I think capture software should not depend too much on the driver. A webcam with a builtin microphone is not more, than an usb device, providing both a sound recording device and a camera device. Any software capable to record both of them simultanously, would do. Manufacturers tend to insert some simple tool beside their product, these are mostly not very useful. In your case I would look for generic video recording software.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica -- I'm not looking for recording software.  I have little choice about that. This will be used for videoconferencing.  I'll add it to the needs.

Comment: If you can tell me how to zoom in with a C920 without using their stupid Capture program, you're better at finding things then I am.  I've been trying for at least a year.

Comment: If their stupid capture tool is the only way to zoom, then they are an unfair producer and should be avoided. I gave you an up - I wish you an useful answer soon.

Comment: The Logitech C920 does not have optical zoom. You can do a digital zoom using OBS and the VirtualCamera addon, which works quite well.

Comment: @Rubydesic, optical zoom is not necessary, and those software solutions are not simple enough.